# Open Graph Protocol - og:movie with youtube link

Tags: facebook, youtube, embed, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

Wanted scenario:

- people link to my website via Facebook
- open graph data pops up (name, description, thumbnail, ...) (which works)
- when you click the thumbnail a youtube video plays (which doesn't work)

Facebook seems to know that there is a video to be played, but doesn't want to go through with it.

My code:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<url>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<name>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<description>" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/S3_AwK3ujQI&fs=1" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="560" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="315" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<link rel="video_src" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/S3_AwK3ujQI&fs=1"  />
<meta name="video_type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta name="video_width" content="560" />
<meta name="video_height" content="315" />
```

What seems to be wrong? I read somewhere that the solution has to do something with SSL, but since I link to a external YouTube video that shouldn't be the case; or is it?

Comment: I have this problem too, I've used the same og tags as you wanting it to show a video in Facebook, but it doesn't show a video unless you specify an exact video file (which most tutorials tell me), but I want to use a youtube video - not host my own

Answer (score 1):

You also need an og:picture. Using https for the video url will let it play for people who have Facebook on secure. Go to a youtube page and check out what they're using for og tags.